I want to invoke @Test in TestNg only when a boolean flag is true and note I dont want to use SkipException
I am using TestNg for Test Automation. I want to enable test only when a certain flag is true.
for example
boolean isEnabled =  true;
see with enabled attribute of @Test it can't be achieved as it does not accept variables.
and I don't want to use SkipException
I tried using some of the Listener it didnt work.

You might want to share some code of what you tried and maybe elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve. Is this some kind of fast vs slow tests thing where you don't want to always run the slow tests? If so, test suites might be what you're looking for.

it is like, I have to enable those test only when a certain condition matched. I do have an option of if block within those tests and use SkipException but this leads to skipped test in report which I don;t want

You should be able to build a TestNG listener that leverages org.testng.IMethodInterceptor and get this done.
A few facts:

There's a TestNG listener named org.testng.IMethodInterceptor which gets called by TestNG before the test methods start running wherein, you can add/remove one or more @Test methods from the execution plan.
There's a TestNG listener named org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener which lets you modify a parsed <suite> tag and you can add/modify <test> tags within it.

Steps to follow:

Build a TestNG listener that implements IMethodInterceptor and IAlterSuiteListener
The implementation of IAlterSuiteListener will basically query the system properties (the ones that you pass via -D JVM argument) and look for a system property named exclude_methods and if it finds this property, then it will alter all the <suite> tags and programmatically add a <parameter> named exclude_methods to it.
The implementation of IMethodInterceptor will basically parse the <suite> parameter's and look for a parameter named exclude_methods and if it is found, it will split it to n values (because we are going to allow the value to be comma separated) and for each of the split value, it will escape sequence any meta characters that regex knows of and one the escape sequenced method name it tries to pattern match the input exclusion list and thus prune the list of methods.

You can wire in this listener using one of the below mechanisms:

via the @Listener annotation (or)
via the <listener> tag in the suite file (or)
via service loading mechanism.

For more details on wiring in TestNG listeners, please refer to the official documentation.
For learning more about method interceptors, please refer here.
Note: Ensure that you are using the latest released version of TestNG v7.10.2
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SimpleMethodSelector implements IMethodInterceptor, IAlterSuiteListener {
    private static final List<Pattern> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String EXCLUDE_METHODS = "exclude_methods";

    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        //Let's check if there were any methods provided to us to be ignored via the JVM argument
        String excludeMethods = System.getProperty(EXCLUDE_METHODS, "");
        if (!excludeMethods.isEmpty()) {
            //If there were some patterns (can be comma separated) then lets add this
            //as a parameter into the <suite> tag.
            suites.forEach(it -> it.getParameters().put(EXCLUDE_METHODS, excludeMethods));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        buildExclusionPatterns(context);
        if (patterns.isEmpty()) {
            //If there were no patterns to be considered, then it means that the user wants to execute everything
            return methods;
        }
        return methods.stream()
                .filter(it -> !shouldExcludeMethod(it.getMethod()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static boolean shouldExcludeMethod(ITestNGMethod itm) {
        return patterns.stream()
                .anyMatch(
                        pattern -> methodNamesToConsider(itm)
                                .anyMatch(name -> pattern.matcher(name).matches())
                );
    }

    private static Stream<String> methodNamesToConsider(ITestNGMethod itm) {
        return Stream.of(
                itm.getQualifiedName(),//Match fully qualified method name (or)
                itm.getMethodName() //Match just method name without fully qualified class name
        );
    }

    private static void buildExclusionPatterns(ITestContext context) {
        if (!patterns.isEmpty()) {
            //If we already built the pattern once, then lets not doing again and again
            //because this method will be called for each and every test method within a <test> tag
            return;
        }

        //Check if the current <test> tag contains the parameter "exclude_methods"
        String excludedMethods = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter(EXCLUDE_METHODS);
        if (Optional.ofNullable(excludedMethods).orElse("").isEmpty()) {
            //If there were no methods to be excluded, then there's nothing to process.
            //Lets return
            return;
        }
        for (String method : excludedMethods.split(",")) {
            String escapedMethod = escape(method); //Escape sequence all the regex special characters
            System.err.println("Working with pattern " + escapedMethod);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(escapedMethod, Pattern.DOTALL);
            patterns.add(pattern);
        }
    }

    private static String escape(String text) {
        return text.chars()
                .mapToObj(SimpleMethodSelector::asString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    //Refer https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-regex/index.html#metacharacters for more details
    private static final List<Character> META_CHARACTERS = List.of(
            '<', '>', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '^', '-', '=',
            '$', '!', '|', '?', '*', '+', '.'
    );

    private static String asString(int it) {
        return META_CHARACTERS.contains((char) it) ? "\\\\" + (char) it : Character.toString(it);
    }
}

A sample test case that looks like below:
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestCase {

    @Test
    public void a() {
        System.err.println(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod().getQualifiedName() + "()");
    }

    @Test
    public void b() {
        System.err.println(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod().getQualifiedName() + "()");
    }

    @Test
    public void c() {
        System.err.println(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod().getQualifiedName() + "()");
    }
}

Here's a sample suite file
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="78547470_suite" verbose="2">
    <parameter name="exclude_methods" value=""/>
    <test name="78547470_test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78547470.SampleTestCase"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Here's the run configuration when running this test via IntelliJ

Here's the execution output
...
... TestNG 7.10.2 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

Working with pattern \\*b\\*
com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78547470.SampleTestCase.a()
com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78547470.SampleTestCase.c()
PASSED: com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78547470.SampleTestCase.c
PASSED: com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78547470.SampleTestCase.a

===============================================
    78547470_test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

